# Adding double within a parallel loop - std::atomic<double>

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, parallel.for

I have a parallel code that does some computation and then adds a double to an outside-the-loop double variable. I tried using std::atomic but it does not have suport for arithmetic operations on std::atomic < double > variables.

```
double dResCross = 0.0;
std::atomic<double> dResCrossAT = 0.0;

Concurrency::parallel_for(0, iExperimentalVectorLength, [&](size_t m)
{
     double value;
     //some computation of the double value
     atomic_fetch_add(&dResCrossAT, value);
});
dResCross += dResCrossAT;
```

Simply writing

```
dResCross += value;
```

does obviously otput nonsense. My question is, how can I solve this problem, without making the code serial?

Answer (score 3):

A typical way to atomically perform arithmetic operations on a floating-point type is with a compare-and-swap (CAS) loop.

```
 double value;
 //some computation of the double value

 double expected = atomic_load(&dResCrossAT);

 while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&dResCrossAT, &expected, expected + value));
```

A detailed explanation can be found in [Jeff Preshing's article](https://preshing.com/20150402/you-can-do-any-kind-of-atomic-read-modify-write-operation/) about this class of operation.

Comment: I've seen similar code with `expected` empty (or zero); The CAS then uodates it.. Isn't that simpler ?

Comment: @Tootsie It is not wrong to do that and it even seems simpler because you get rid of the load. Problem is that the CAS now has to be executed twice which is a pessimization compared to one load+CAS

Answer (score 0):

I believe excluding partial memory write in a non-atomic variable requires mutexing, I am not certain of that being the only way to ensure there is no write conflict but it is accomplished like this

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;

void threadFunction(double* d){
    while (*d < 100) {
        mtx.lock();
        *d += 1.0;
        mtx.unlock();
    }
}

int main() {
    double* d = new double(0);
    std::thread thread(threadFunction, d);
    while (true) {
        if (*d == 100) {
            break;
        }
    }
    thread.join();
}
```

Which will add `1.0` to `d` 100 times in a thread-safe way. The mutex locking and unlocking ensures that only one thread is accessing `d` at a given time. However, this is significantly slower than an `atomic` equivalent because locking and unlocking is so expensive - I've heard varying things based on operating system and specific processor and what is being locked or unlocked but it's in the neighborhood of 50 clock cycles for this example, but it can require a system call which is more like 2000 clock cycles.

**Moral**: use with caution.

Comment: You are correct that a `std:mutex` can protect a variable that is read/write accessed concurrently, but the reading part also needs protection, not just the writing

Comment: If the variable being read is shared memory why would parallel read require protection? Is it because the possibility of another thread starting a write while a thread is mid read?

Comment: Reading from a non-atomic variable while another thread is writing to it is not allowed by the C++ standard. It's technically undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If your vector has many elements per thread, you should consider implementing a reduction rather than using an atomic operation for every element. Atomic operations are much more expensive than normal stores.

```
double global_value{0.0};
std::vector<double> private_values(num_threads,0.0);
parallel_for(size_t k=0; k<n; ++k) {
    private_values[my_thread] += ...;
}
if (my_thread==0) {
    for (int t=0; t<num_threads; ++t) {
         global_value += private_values[t];
    }
}
```

This algorithm requires no atomic operations and will be faster in many cases. You can replace the second phase with a tree or atomics if the thread count is very high (e.g. on a GPU).

Concurrency libraries like TBB and Kokkos both provide parallel reduce templates that do the right thing internally.